# cwac-wakeful library - NullPointerException in AlarmReceiver

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I've implemented commonsware wakeful library and for the most it is working fine. but sometimes i get the following exception :

> 01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397): Unable to start receiver com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2287)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver.getListener(AlarmReceiver.java:66)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:36)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2280)
>   01-11 04:24:00.018 E/CustomExceptionHandler - Exception statcktrace( 7397):     ... 10 more

As you can see this originates in AlarmReceiver.getListener(). I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

I also tried a different approach which was to avoid using the listener resource xml file at all (which is my suspected root cause for this exception). I did that by creating a custom class that extends com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver and overriden getListener(). I Also changed the reference in the manifest file. But, for some reason, now sendWakefulWork is not called at all and the scheduled service is not executed.

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful` `<meta-data>` in the manifest, as [line 66 of `AlarmReceiver.java`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/blob/v1.0.5/wakeful/src/com/commonsware/cwac/wakeful/AlarmReceiver.java#L66) is the first line trying to read in that metadata. The only time that I can think of this could happen only some of the time would be on broken ROMs or on hacked versions of your app (where the metadata got stripped for some reason). If it were a coding error (e.g., you have the `<meta-data>` element in the wrong place), it should happen all of the time.

> I did that by creating a custom class that extends com.commonsware.cwac.wakeful.AlarmReceiver and overriden getListener().

`WakefulIntentService` does not support that. If you do not want to use `AlarmReceiver`, that is fine, but do not call `scheduleAlarms()` or `cancelAlarms()`. Instead, just use `sendWakefulWork()`, as is described in [the "Basic Usage" section of the documentation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful#basic-usage).

Comment: By saying "but sometimes i get the following exception" i mean that this happens for some users. We are using your library currently in production and some of the users get this problem. I have the <meta-data> element positioned correctly in the manifest and on my tests i dont get this exception.

Comment: I dont quite understand, If i want to avoid using your AlarmReceiver (only because it is using an xml resource) but still wants to execute the service as a scheduled task how will i do that ? do i need to create my own receiver that its only job will be to call sendWakefulWork and set this receiver with AlarmManager as a scheduled task ?

Comment: @AsafK: "do i need to create my own receiver that its only job will be to call sendWakefulWork and set this receiver with AlarmManager as a scheduled task ?" -- yes.